# perl is not freeing memory, what could be the reason?

Tags: perl, dispose

**Edit 1**:
I've following logic in perl file, (added output file handler).

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        my $outputFile=$i."_out";
        open(outputHandler, ">$outputFile") or die "Couldn't open output file: $!";
        my $filePath = $i;
        open(Rfile_handle, $filePath) or die("Could't open input file: $!");
        while (<Rfile_handle>) {
            my $line = $_;
            #Do processing - line by line. Read global variable - no edit/update
            #add required fields in my $outputLine variable
            print outputHandler "$outputLine\n";
        }
        close Rfile_handle;
        close outputHandler;
    }
```

Still I see same behavior. I see memory usage is constantly increasing. I've to kill the process and rerun the program from the last line executed.
This is exactly what I'm doing. There is no change in the code, except the logic part of assigning and extracting data from json. Now, can we infer anything? or what am I doing wrong?

**End of Edit 1**

I'm a novice programmer in perl. I used code in c#.
I've around 10 files around 5GB each. I need to read & process them one-by-one. My system RAM size is only 4GB. So, I used following way to read files in for loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    my $filePath = i;
    open(Rfile_handle, $filePath) or die("Could't open input file: $!");
    while (<Rfile_handle>) {
        my $line = $_;
        //Do processing - line by line
    }
    close Rfile_handle;
}
```

When I see task manager it shows, memory usage is increasing.
Shouldn't perl free the memory after completing one file and resue it for next file, like c# does it for me? As task manager shows, it is not freeing the memory. Can I dispose/deallocate memory somehow?

I've tried `undef`, but it doesn't free up the memory.

What should I do? and what is the best way to read files of such huge size in perl?
I want a way to reuse the memory occupied by the variables in for loop.

Note: I can't use any other scripting or programming language.

Comment: There's nothing like `int i` in Perl.

Comment: I meant my $i :)
Sorry, for mistype.

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about it. Perl looks like it uses more memory, because it's using internal memory management. It does still free up and re-use internally. It just for obvious reasons has to balloon to the max size of your memory footprint.

In general, the way of ensuring perl is as efficent as possible:

- lexically scope variables (especially arrays/hashes) - perl can then figure out when they're no longer used. (It uses reference counting to keep track.).
- use `while` loops to read files line by line, rather than a foreach loop. (Which will read the whole file into a temp array first)

More generally - you should probably be using a 3 argument open, as two arguments is bad style.

So you should in your code do:

```
open ( my $input_fh, "<", $filepath ) or die $!;

while( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
    #do stuff; 
}
```

`$output_fh` will drop ref count to zero at the end of your 'for' loop and be closed and deallocated.

What are you storing as you're processing your file in the while loop? Perl won't - by default - use memory equal to file size, unless you're 'saving' the whole line somehow?

Oh, and you have a bug:

```
my $filePath=i;
```

This'll set your `$filePath` to a file called `i` which isn't going to work. Turn on:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

and you'll be told about this sort of problem. (Same problem in your `for` loop. `i` is not a valid variable name in perl, you should be using `$i`.

See also:

http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-free-an-array-or-hash-so-my-program-shrinks-

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-make-my-Perl-program-take-less-memory%3f

As a result of how perl uses reference counting, there is a 'gotcha' in perl - you can create circular chains of references. Because they're still referenced, perl won't garbage collect. If you're in danger of having this problem, you can use `weaken()` from `Scalar::Util`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. 
But what happens once the RAM usage is more than 4 GB :|, atleast by seeing the trend it looks to me that it will cross the ram size. I needn't worry about it and let perl handle it?
my $filePath=i; not a bug, as I've files named as 1,2,3..10. :)

Comment: Then you probably mean `$i` not `i` :) (Which is incidentally - redundant, as you could just use `$i` in your `open` directly) - this also applies to your 'for' loop.

Comment: If you're using 4GB, then _something_ is storing data in memory. Processing a file line by line isn't doing this - nothing is retained in memory. Are you sure you're not updating a global variable/hash/array somewhere?

Comment: I've few global arrays, which I'm just reading in the loop. I've local arrays in the loop, which i'm re-initializing based on data processing. So, logically  memory used by local arrays should reused, right?
But I don't see that happening.

Comment: Depends - what are you doing to re-init? `undef()` doesn't do what you might be thinking it does. Far better to use `my` and let perl garbage collect when something goes out of scope.

Comment: I'm using my variables in local. 100% sure not updating global arrays/hash. I'm just reading values from it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing your processing line-by-line as shown by the code in the question (as opposed to storing the entire file contents into an array, hash, or other data structure) and the consumed memory is substantially larger than the amount of data per line, then you most likely have a memory leak in your processing code - you're using a variable whose reference count never falls to 0 (probably due to circular references in a data structure), so Perl is never able to reuse that memory.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, as the processing code is omitted. Local scoping of lexicals helps, but that's not going to do very much good if there's a global array that's getting each line of the file `push()`ed into it. But it's a good point - and one of the 'gotchas' of perls memory management is that you can create circular chains of references. The `weaken` function in Scalar::Util helps for that.

Comment: The line is a json string. I'm using JSON::Parse to parse it and get values for json keys in while loop.

Comment: Reusing a parser, or instantiating a new one each time? What are you doing with the extracted?

Comment: In while loop, I'm doing following,

my $line = $_;
chomp($line);
my $json = lc($line);
my $perl = parse_json ($json);

Now, through $perl I'm accessing the json values and relevant values I'm writing into output file in while loop.